# change the src value of an image based on the options value in a select box

Tags: jquery

I have an img tag and a select box

```
<img src="" name="image-swap">

<select name="kitchen_color" id="kitchen_color">
    <option value="/static/imag1.jpg">Red</option>
    <option value="/static/imag2.jpg">Black</option>
    <option value="/static/imag3.jpg">White</option>

</select>
```

I need to change the src value of the img tag based on the select box value.

If I select the option RED the the value of the option Red(/static/imag1.jpg) should fill in the src of the image.

And also select the first option value as the default image.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#kitchen_color").change(function(){
     $("img[name=image-swap]").attr("src",$(this).val());

   });

});
```

Use above code.

Comment: Thanks yaar so simple. As i am a very beginner to jquery i feel it very difficult..thanks........

Comment: how can i set up the default image ? i need the first value in the select box as my default image...

Comment: @give the value in the src and same in the value of first option of select box.

Answer (score 2):

use a change function on your select list

```
$('#kitchen_color').change( function() {    
$("#imgid").attr("src","new src value");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `onchange` event to the `select`.

```
<select name="kitchen_color" id="kitchen_color" onchange="setImage(this);">
  <option value="https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo4w.png">Google</option>
  <option value="http://yandex.st/www/1.645/yaru/i/logo.png">Yandex</option>
  <option value="http://limg.imgsmail.ru/s/images/logo/logo.v2.png">Mail</option>
</select><br />
<img src="" name="image-swap" />
```

Javascript:

```
function setImage(select){
  var image = document.getElementsByName("image-swap")[0];
  image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Example [there](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/NWbsj/)

Answer (score 0):

```
try this


<img src="" class="image-swap">

<select name="kitchen_color" id="kitchen_color" onchange="change_image()">
    <option value="/static/imag1.jpg">Red</option>
    <option value="/static/imag2.jpg">Black</option>
    <option value="/static/imag3.jpg">White</option>

</select>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.image-swap').attr("src",$('#kitchen_color').val());
})

function change_image(){
    $('.image-swap').attr("src",$('#kitchen_color').val());
}
```