# Function undefined while trying to modify values with it and with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 3 different files:

ajax.js

```
function ajaxPreTier(index) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data:{action: 'setPreTierImg', i: index},
            success:function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
  }

  function ajaxPostTier(index) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data:{action: 'setPostTierImg', i: index},
            success:function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
  }
```

ajax.php

```
       <!-- ajax.php -->

<script>

    function setPreTierImg() {
        switch($_POST['i']) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("preTier").src = 'images/bronze_rank.png';
                break;
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("preTier").src = 'images/silver_rank.png';
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("preTier").src = 'images/gold_rank.png';
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("preTier").src = 'images/platinum_rank.png';
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("preTier").src = 'images/diamond_rank.png';
                break;
        }
    }

    function setPostTierImg() {
        switch($_POST['i']) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("postTier").src = 'images/bronze_rank.png';
                break;
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("postTier").src = 'images/silver_rank.png';
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("postTier").src = 'images/gold_rank.png';
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("postTier").src = 'images/platinum_rank.png';
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("postTier").src = 'images/diamond_rank.png';
                break;
        }
    }

</script>

<?php


if($_POST['action'] == 'setPreTierImg') {
    setPreTierImg();
}

if($_POST['action'] == 'setPostTierImg') {
    setPostTierImg();
}



?>
```

test2.php

```
<html>
<head>
---
---
   <script src="ajax.js"></script>

<?php
                        echo "<form action='./test2.php' method='post'>
                            <select name='tier' style='width:100%;' onclick='ajaxPreTier(this.selectedIndex)'>
                                <option value='1'>Bronze</option>
                                <option value='2'>Silver</option>
                                <option value='3'>Gold</option>
                                <option value='4'>Platinum</option>
                                <option value='5'>Diamond</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name='division' style='width:100%;'>
                                <option value='1'>I</option>
                                <option value='2'>II</option>
                                <option value='3'>III</option>
                                <option value='4'>IV</option>
                                <option value='5'>V</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name='lp' style='width:100%;'>
                                <option value='1'>0-20</option>
                                <option value='2'>21-40</option>
                                <option value='3'>41-60</option>
                                <option value='4'>61-80</option>
                                <option value='5'>81-100</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='1' />
                            <input type='submit' name='add_to_cart' value='Add to cart' style='width:206%;'/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>";

              echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="width:50%;">
                <div>
                  <div class="item-icon">
                    <img id="postTier" src="images/bronze_rank.png" style="width:100%"></img>
                    <p style="line-height: 60px;">Your finished division</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-details">';
                            echo "<select name='post_tier' style='width:100%;' onclick='ajaxPostTier(this.selectedIndex)'>
                                <option value='1'>Bronze</option>
                                <option value='2'>Silver</option>
                                <option value='3'>Gold</option>
                                <option value='4'>Platinum</option>
                                <option value='5'>Diamond</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name='post_division' style='width:100%;'>
                                <option value='1'>I</option>
                                <option value='2'>II</option>
                                <option value='3'>III</option>
                                <option value='4'>IV</option>
                                <option value='5'>V</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>";
                        ?>

</head>
</html>
```

Inside the test2.php I have some php code where I have an input from the user to choose a certain option. When the option is chosen, The select has an onclick button which callbacks to my two functions: ajaxPreTier(index) and ajaxPostTier(index). Then it goes to ajax.php
Inside my ajax.php I have added the functions that I'm using but the functions `setPreTierImg()` and `setPostTierImg()` are always unidentified.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwTpG.png)

Comment: Your `ajax.js` has PHP in it..

Comment: Woops. Just noticed, do you know where I should put the setPreTierImg function? I've tried in every single file.

Comment: It looks like a mix of PHP and JS.

Comment: @chris85 do you mind taking a second look at it? I've changed now but I still get an error.

Comment: Why is the javascript inside the php tags?

Comment: you are writing JS in PHP, that won't work.

Comment: @Garytje do you have a solution on how to fix this? The problem is that I have to use PHP to get the values from the ajax function and then I need to modify the values in a HTML element. And with that I'm using javascript.

Comment: @Nikki9696 thanks for seeing that, I've updated it now, if you know anything further that I need to change.

Comment: No, you don't have to use ajax in my opinion. Explain to us what you want to achieve, because it looks like you want to show an image depending on the chosen select option, that can be done in javascript solely.

Comment: It would appear that you just need to break up the logic properly between JS and PHP.  When the user selects an option from the drop down, you should update the image source with JS on the page AND you should send the new selection to your PHP code (probably for persistence) via AJAX (i.e. more JS on the same page.)

Comment: @Garytje That is exactly what I want to do. I have 5 different options. Based on the selection, the images above the options have the id "preTier" and "postTier" and based on the values I want to change the source of the image.

Comment: I'm with @Garytje i think you're overcomplicating this. Just pop out possible images into an array or something the first time and avoid a lot of headaches.  =)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054609/change-the-src-value-of-an-image-based-on-the-options-value-in-a-select-box should get you on your way!

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone, @Garytje the only problem I have left is that I don't know how to get the object without using $(this) as my values need to be 1-5. I've set it up with an array of images, but to get the correct image I still need the index of the option to use it in the array. How do I do that in jquery?

Comment: take a look at the answer i gave you 15m ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your select the id `tier` and the image that needs to change `image`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#tier").change(function(){
    console.log($(this.val()); // check console for value
    switch($(this).val()) {
        case 0:
           newsrc = 'images/bronze_rank.png';
            break;
        case 1:
            newsrc = 'images/silver_rank.png';
            break;
        case 2:
           newsrc = 'images/gold_rank.png';
            break;
        case 3:
            newsrc = 'images/platinum_rank.png';
            break;
        case 4:
           newsrc = 'images/diamond_rank.png';
            break;
    }
     $("#image").attr("src",newsrc);

   });

});
```

No need for Ajax or posts.. just Javascript

Comment: I've added the code at the bottom with my other scripts inside a script tag but nothings seems to change when I have the code. Console still says that the image is the default one as it shows. Am I putting it in the wrong location?

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, the only thing you need is test2.php and add this code within a script tag. i've edited my post to add a console.log of the value, what does it give you if you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding something.

1. PHP is pre-processor for html. Remember that php file is translated into static html file when client requests. php does not understand javascript. Meaning that `<script src="ajax.js"></script>` will not executed. That line will be treated as a plain text. Move `setPreTierImg` and `setPostTierImg` outside of javascript file and paste them after `<?php` tag if you want to call inside your php file.
   Then, this will fix your undefined function call error.
2. Dynamic DOM manipulation is the part of javascript which is totally executed on the client side.
   Apparently, you are trying to change image url dynamically on user selection. Technically, you can do it (see [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)) but, seriously don't have to.
   just change those Img function into javascript format and attach listener on them, not ajax function.