# Displaying a specific picture depending on multiple select lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

right now I'm doing something for work and I'm not really a coder so I'm having a bit of difficulty with this. So basically, I have 4 select lists that look like this:

```
<img class="stylephoto" id="image" src="Null_Image.png" />
<table class="styletable">

  <select class="styleclass" id="fencelist">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
    <option value="Arrow">Arrow</option>
  </select>

  <select class="styleclass" id="stylelist">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
    <option value="Fence">Fence</option>
    <option value="1 Door Gate">1 Door Gate</option>
    <option value="2 Door Gate">2 Door Gate</option>
  </select>`

  <select class="styleclass" id="panellist">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
    <option value="Spear">Spear</option>
    <option value="Triad">Triad</option>
  </select>

  <select class="styleclass" id="raillist">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
    <option value="Scroll">Scroll</option>
    <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
    <option value="X">X</option>
  </select>
```

Using javascript, I made it so that depending on the chosen value of the first select (id = `fencelist`), the photo will display a different photo.

```
var changeimage = function() {
  document.getElementById('image').src =
    this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + "_Image.png"
}
fencelist = document.getElementById('fencelist');
fencelist.addEventListener('change', changeimage, false);
```

Basically, I want all of the selects to change the display of the picture, so instead of just `Arrow_Image.png`, I would want it to be `ArrowFenceSpearScroll_Image.png`.

I hope this explanation was enough and I appreciate your help.

Comment: You'll need to take a look at `onchange()` listener

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change the src value of an image based on the options value in a select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054609/change-the-src-value-of-an-image-based-on-the-options-value-in-a-select-box)

Answer (score 0):

this keyword in JS is used to point towards the object Environment/function Environment , so here this points only towards the select having id = "fencelist"...

```
document.querySelectorAll(".styleclass").forEach(function(val){
   console.log("It's working" , val.value);
    val.onchange = function(){
          changeimage();
         }
});

var changeimage = function() {
var ImageName = "";

 document.querySelectorAll(".styleclass").forEach(function(val){
        ImageName += val.value;
     });       
document.getElementById("image").src = ImageName + "_Image.png";

};
```

Hope this works for you...

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of ID for event listener. You cannot call multiple elements from ID.
 Check Below code

HTML

```
  <select class="styleclass" id="fencelist">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
    <option value="Arrow">Arrow</option>
  </select>

  <select class="styleclass" id="stylelist">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
    <option value="Fence">Fence</option>
    <option value="1 Door Gate">1 Door Gate</option>
    <option value="2 Door Gate">2 Door Gate</option>
  </select>`

  <select class="styleclass" id="panellist">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
    <option value="Spear">Spear</option>
    <option value="Triad">Triad</option>
  </select>

  <select class="styleclass" id="raillist">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
    <option value="Scroll">Scroll</option>
    <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
    <option value="X">X</option>
  </select>
```

JS

```
var changeimage = function() {
  document.getElementById('image').src =
    this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + "_Image.png"
}
fencelist = document.getElementsByClassName('styleclass'); // all selects contains this class
fencelist.addEventListener('change', changeimage, false);
```